# print same ID for all the elements in text1 and then icrementing the ID and priting for text2. -Python

Tags: python

I have 2 text files text1.txt and text2.txt.

text1.txt contains:

```
sam
mat
tom
```

text2.txt contains:

```
robbie
peter
steve
```

I want the output to be something like:-

```
sam1
mat1
tom1
robbie2
peter2
steve2
```

So for text1.txt elements, I want to print the same ID for all the elements and then increment the ID by 1 and print it corresponding to the elements/names in text2.txt as shown above.

Any help?
Thanks

Comment: First share what have you tried.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this out:

```
files = ['text1.txt', 'text2.txt']

for (id, file) in enumerate(files, start=1):
    with open(file, 'r') as f:
        for line in f.xreadlines():
            print line.strip() + str(id)
```

Comment: What if I want to start my ID from 1 and not 0?

Comment: @sam call enumerate with `start`, i.e. `enumerate(files, start=1)`

Comment: @sam - Like mhawke has shown - I've edited my answer accordingly.

Comment: @shadow also, id is printed on a separate line, not the same line.

Comment: @mhawke - Ah, pesky newlines. sam - I've edited the code to make IDs print on the same line.

Answer (score 1):

```
>>> for i, f in enumerate([open('text1.txt'), open('text2.txt')], start=1):
...     for line in f:
...             print '%s%s' % (line.strip(), i)
...     f.close()
... 
sam1
mat1
tom1
robbie2
peter2
steve2
```